# How to convert gif to webm on upload using paperclip and/or paperclip-av-transcoder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

All docs describe how to create thumbnails out of videos. But what if I don't want to store the original large gif files, but convert them to webm videos which are of a much smaller size?

```
class MediaAttachment < ApplicationRecord
  IMAGE_MIME_TYPES = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'].freeze
  VIDEO_MIME_TYPES = ['video/webm', 'video/mp4'].freeze

  has_attached_file :file,
                    styles: -> (f) { file_styles f },
                    processors: -> (f) { f.video? ? [:transcoder] : [:thumbnail] },
                    convert_options: { all: '-quality 90 -strip' }
  validates_attachment_content_type :file, content_type: IMAGE_MIME_TYPES + VIDEO_MIME_TYPES
  validates_attachment_size :file, less_than: 4.megabytes

  def image?
    IMAGE_MIME_TYPES.include? file_content_type
  end

  def video?
    VIDEO_MIME_TYPES.include? file_content_type
  end

  class << self
    private

    def file_styles(f)
      if f.instance.image?
        {
          original: '1280x1280>',
          small: '400x400>',
        }
      else
        {
          small: {
            convert_options: {
              output: {
                vf: 'scale=\'min(400\, iw):min(400\, ih)\':force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease',
              },
            },
            format: 'png',
            time: 1,
          },
        }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The above code allows users to upload images or webm/mp4 videos, and creates a thumbnail out of the videos. How do I make it so gifs are converted and stored as webms (and then a thumbnail is generated just like for other videos)?